# Parse.com Retrieve type "date"

Tags: android, datetime, parse-platform

how do I retrieve type "date" from my class. Do I need to change it to String first ? 
I can get String type and boolean type but cant get date/time from my database.

Click the image example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXgFg.png

Mycode:

```
  public class AttendanceList extends Activity{
  private TextView code;
  private TextView name;
  private TextView section;
  private TextView date;
  String subcode;
  String subname;
  String subsection;
// Date subdate;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance_list);
  code=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sub_code);
  name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sub_name);
  section=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sub_section);
  date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=ParseQuery.getQuery("TME2301");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
@Override
public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
  if(e==null){
   for(ParseObject object:parseObjects){

   subcode=object.getString("Subject_code");
   subname=object.getString("Subject_name");
   subsection=object.getString("Subject_section");
   //subdate=object.getDate("date");
   code.setText(subcode);
   name.setText(subname);
   section.setText(subsection);
}
}
}
});
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   java.util.Date subdate; 
   try {
      subdate=object.getDate("date");
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy, kk:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
      String subdateStr = df.format(subdate);
      date.setText(subdateStr);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      // log error
    }
```

Comment: Errors : Incompatible types.
Required:com.example.joshua.faceattendance.Date,Found:java.util.Date 
http://i.imgur.com/NsFThxi.png @IsabelHM

Comment: that's because your subdate is Date, not java.util.Date

Comment: okay,thanks . I import java.util.Date; and solved. Now another problem : http://i.imgur.com/yqqA4gj.png @IsabelHM

Comment: the last part i changed to date.setText(subdateStr); and it worked perfectly ! Thanks a lot !! @IsabelHM